# Потеря страницы в Nuxt-приложении на устройстве с Android

Tags: маршрутизация, nuxt.js

В Nuxt-приложении на мобильном с Android (на других мобильных ОС не проверял) при возврате на предыщую страницу с помощью андроидовской кнопки "Назад" страница не отображается, отображается только ее лэйаут. На десктопе, когда нажимаю в браузере кнопку "Назад", такой проблемы нет, даже в devtools в режиме эмуляции мобильного все работет нормально. В чем может быть причина?